# What's it called when multiple "and"s are used in the same list to create emphasis?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, and-and

In semi-poetic writing, I have had occasion to deviate from the standard prose list practice (interpose commas or semicolons between items, with an "and" preceding the final item), by utilizing a second or third *and* to separate three or four items.  That is,

> Bob likes beer, wine and liquor.

The variant would be:

> Bob likes beer **and** wine **and** liquor.

Now, the usage is obviously nonstandard and should be avoided in formal writing, but for those instances where poetic variation may be justified.

What is it called?

"Emphatic And" is the best I can coin on my own, but I wonder if there is a more established name for this variation.

Comment: You don't hear the emphasis?  The former is a simple listing of preference; the latter has a subtle implication of excess.  (Is Bob a connoisseur, or an alcoholic?)

Comment: There's a special name for leaving out all but the last _and_ in a series. Why do you want a special name for leaving in what's already there?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysyndeton

Comment: To reinforce that you intentionally left out commas, you may want to italicise the "ands":

> Bob likes beer *and* wine *and* liquor.

Just a suggestion - you may think its too heavy-handed depending on your intended audience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called ***polysyndeton***, and creates a ***polysyndetic co-ordination.***

> Polysyndeton is the use of several conjunctions in close succession, especially where some might be omitted (as in "he ran and jumped and laughed for joy"). The word "polysyndeton" comes from the Greek "poly-", meaning "many," and "syndeton", meaning "bound together with". It is a stylistic scheme used to achieve a variety of effects: it can increase the rhythm of prose, speed or slow its pace, convey solemnity or even ecstasy and childlike exuberance. Another common use of polysyndeton is to create a sense of being overwhelmed, or in fact directly overwhelm the audience by using conjunctions, rather than commas, leaving little room for a reader to breathe.
>
> [[Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysyndeton)

The opposite, leaving out every conjunction, is called *asyndeton*.

Answer (score -1):

Since Bob likes 3 items, each item should be separated by a comma:

***Bob likes beer, wine, and liquor.***

Now, if the last two items (wine and liquor) are one item (e.g. macaroni and cheese, peanut butter and jelly, rum and coke) then no comma is needed:

***Bob likes beer, wine, and rum and coke.***

Comment: The question is asking for what it's called when you have two *and*s, not what the rule for standard English is.